# How to prevent role change when you get a validation error when you type the wrong password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, devise, edit

```
<%-roles = Role.all%>

<%= panel "Edit" do%>

 <%= semantic_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <% f.inputs do %>
  <p><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>
  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></p>
  <%=f.input :roles,:collection => Role.all%>
<% end %>
    <% f.buttons do %>
<%=f.submit "Update" %></p>
<% end %>
```

In here, when I don't type any password in, the error message shows but also the role of the user gets changed as well. How do I make it so that the role doesn't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's role changes are in memory, no in database. You can do model.reload to discard memory changes and reload your user from database if a validation error happens.

Comment: I want to make it so that it doesn't alter the data when I try to submit something with wrong confirmation password

Comment: fixed!! The routing was messed up